# How can I write parameters into ApexChart in Vue.js via props?

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

is there any option, how to set ApexChart parameters dynamically via Props or anything else?
I want to make a wrapper for ApexCharts. First parameter should be type of chart and I looking for a way, how to set this parameter during creating a new component in Vue.js

```
<apexchart type="{{type}}"
               height="{{height}}"
               ref="centerProjectTreemap"
               :options="chartOptions"
               :series="series"
    ></apexchart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "param-chart",
  props: {
    type: String,
    height: Number
  }
//.......
</script>

<param-chart type="bar" height="350"/> //this is in the main
```

Answer (score 0):

The props binding is the same as other attributes binding, you can do like

```
<apexchart :type="type"
           :height="height"
           ref="centerProjectTreemap"
           :options="chartOptions"
           :series="series"
 ></apexchart>
```

Comment: I did it, but no ApexChart shows. I seen only white div. 
Example is taken from : https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/bar-charts/basic/